# javascript and rails interaction. onclick request a rails path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

This may not be the best coding practice for rails erb. However, I want to handle a button click, how do i do something in the button click and then redirect to url on rails ?

```
<input type="button" onclick="testclick()" value="Test" />

<script type='text/javascript'>
   function testclick() {
    console.log("testclick");

    /* how do i cause this to go to a rails path like link_to "Post", post_path */
   }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a block for a link_to tag:

```
<%= link_to post_path do %>
// your code
<% end %>
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure if you understood. I just wanted on button click, it does some javascript and then redirects to a urlpage in rails.

Comment: this probably is the right answer, got to analyse a bit how this is done http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-technique/

Comment: Inside your test click javascript function you can do something like this: location.href = "<%= post_path %>";

Comment: There's so many ways to answer your question. Just put the button in between the link_to block and you have exactly what your asking for, with zero javascript. If you really want to use JS (for something that absolutely does not require it), you can look up jQuery's on() and click() methods.